# Resolution issue while using two models in a scene in 3d

Tags: android, libgdx, 3dsmax

I have a 3d scene where one of my character(a boy) is standing at the bottom left corner of the screen, after some time it runs and jumps inside a well present at bottom right corner of the screen.

The scene is designed in 3ds max and exported as fbx which is then converted to g3db model and then used in Android. The scene looks and works perfect when running on 1024x600 device but on extra high definition device with resolution around 2500x1600 it jumps half way in the screen.

I tried zooming out the camera but no luck , zooming the camera is also zooming out the character,
any help?

Comment: How does your character determine when to jump (code)?

Comment: In the 3dsmax scene a short audio is played for 3-4 seconds and after that the character jumps(animation).